# PageSpeed Insights ругается на оптимизацию, не могу найти причину такого показателя

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap, pagespeed-insights

PageSpeed Insights Ругается на ужасный показатель, причину того найти не могу, сжал изображения насколько это было возможно с 50 до 9мб, убрал лишний код и подключения, в чем может быть проблема, такому показателю вообще не верю, скорость загрузки страницы ~1с.

[Site](http://ibudakov.beget.tech/)

[PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fibudakov.beget.tech%2F)

Comment: У вас там вполне по русски написано, что можно еще сжать картинки (как вариант можно использовать 2-3 разных сжимателя для лучшего эффекта), подключить минифицированные версии некоторых css и js файлов, и включить кэширование на стороне сервера, что конкретно вам из этого не понятно? А скорость загрузки высокая может достигаться, например, за счет расположенного близко хостинга.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin, мне не понятен бал. 13 баллов десктоп, при том что мобильная версия 68.
А так же не понятно - "включить кэширование на стороне сервера"

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Answer (score 0):

В настоящее время, учитывая первый мобильный индекс Гугл, этот поисковик использует Googlebot для смартфонов.
Для анализа производительности и скорости загрузки для мобильных вы можете использовать инструмент **[WebPagetest](http://www.webpagetest.org/)**.

Например, **[тест главной страницы вашего веб-сайта](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/180610_T9_e136f1b773e89da712fa39f50c49394c/)** показывает скорость загрузки = 5.884 секунд. Сравните это с рекомендацией Гугл для скорости загрузки мобильных **[Мобильный анализ в свойствах PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/mobile)**:

> PageSpeed ​​Insights анализирует страницу, чтобы узнать, соответствует ли она нашим рекомендациям для того, чтобы сделать рендеринг страниц менее чем в секунду в мобильной сети. Исследования показали, что любая задержка дольше, чем секунда, заставит пользователя прервать их поток мысли, создавая плохой опыт.

Для анализа ресурсов веб-страницы, щелкните на *Waterfall*. Выберите наиболее критический ресурс - изображен как самый длинный горизонтальный бар - и щелкните на нем. Там будет указана информация о этом ресурсе.

Для примера можно проверить изображение *img/products/p_preview/5.jpg* - скорость загрузки = 835 миллисекунд. Об этом ресурсе сообщается следующая информация:

- URL: http://ibudakov.beget.tech/img/products/p_preview/5.jpg
- Loaded By: http://ibudakov.beget.tech/:14
- Host: ibudakov.beget.tech
- Error/Status Code: 200 Request ID: 0.14
- Request Start: 1.441 s Time to First Byte: 196 ms
- Content Download: 639 ms Bytes In (downloaded): 11.2 KB
- **Uncompressed Size: 10.9 KB**
- Bytes Out (uploaded): 0 B

Для оптимизации скорости загрузки изображения здесь интересен пункт Uncompressed Size: 10.9 KB - Несжатый размер. Это значит что это изображение не оптимизировано. Используя инструмент **[ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/online)** можно сжать это изображение до 6 КВ, практически без потери качества - выбирая фильтр Low.

Также можно проверить и производительность главной веб-страницы:

- URL: http://ibudakov.beget.tech/
- Host: ibudakov.beget.tech
- Error/Status Code: 200
- Request ID: 0.2
- Request Start: 0.326 s
- DNS Lookup: 61 ms
- Initial Connection: 252 ms
- Time to First Byte: 204 ms
- Content Download: 151 ms
- Bytes In (downloaded): 35.2 KB
- **Uncompressed Size: 35.2 KB**
- Bytes Out (uploaded): 0 B

Опять же обратите внимание на несжатый размер этой веб-страницы = 35.2 КВ. 
Используйте для сжатия исходного кода **[HTML Compressor](https://htmlcompressor.com/compressor/)**. С этим инструментом возможно сжать код главной веб-страницы до, примерно 24 КВ.

Также для проверки производительности вы можете применить тестер Гугл для мобильной выдачи, который показывает, что **[в настоящее время не удалось загрузить 6 ресурсов главной веб-страницы](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly?view=fetch-info&id=WA_5LyoR8JSUZuIQFRipDw)**. Все не загруженные ресурсы понижают скорость загрузки.

Основная проблема производительности вашего веб-сайта возникает при создании моделей **[DOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)** и **[CSSOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/)**. Эти модели браузер создает перед выдачей веб-страницы на экран пользователя. Таким образом **и HTML, и CSS замедляют вывод страницы**. HTML-документ нужно обработать для создания модели DOM, без которой на странице не будет контента.

Когда браузер находит в документе ссылку на CSS-файл, он приостанавливает процесс визуализации и начинает формировать модель CSSOM. По умолчанию при обработке CSS визуализация страницы блокируется.

Дополнительно читайте **[Оптимизация CSS](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css)**.

То же самое относиться к скриптам ваших веб-страниц:

- JavaScript может изменять DOM и CSSOM, а также получать данные из этих моделей.
- Выполнение JavaScript невозможно без модели CSSOM.
- JavaScript препятствует созданию DOM, если не использовать асинхронизацию - **async**.

Дополнительно читайте **[Оптимизация JavaScript для быстрой визуализации страницы](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/adding-interactivity-with-javascript)**.